Client side error when deploying nextJs to Vercel but logs don't provide any insights
I have deployed a nextJs application to vercel. Building and running the application locally there is no issue and all works perfectly.
Once deployed to Vercel the following error message is being display when opening in the brower. The browser console give a link towards react documentation which explains the error but no stacktrace on where the find/resolve the error:
Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).
Looking at the Vercel LOGS, I see this error
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
This is already more, but it doesn't help in which file the error is being triggered. Is there an option to extend the errors being received from either the client and/or Vercel to allow to debug the application?

There are two possible causes for this issue:
A module import or export issue or trying to render something like a React component that’s not a React component.
Module Import or Export Issue
When you import a component into another component, if the component is a named export, you must import it using a named import. The same applies to default exports. If there is a mismatch, your app won’t render and you’ll get the following message on your screen:
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object

You may also get this similar error message that provides potential solutions:
Error
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of App.
This may occur if you try to import a named export variable using a default import:
MyComponent.js
export const myVariable = "hello";

MyOtherComponent.js
import myVariable from "./MyComponent";

It may also occur if you try to import a named export function using a default import:
MyComponent.js
export default function MyComponent() {
  return <div>MyComponent</div>;
}

MyOtherComponent.js
import { MyComponent } from "./MyComponent";

Try to check all your imports. If you have export default make sure you are importing it correctly w/o using {} syntax.

I will try the above and look into the various files. Running the local build doesn't trigger any issue. Any idea why the local build doesn't fail?
